# Count and Q/F query with django

Tags: django, count, django-queryset

I want to use Q/F objects with a Count and I get the following error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Count'
```

I want to get all the deals such that:

- the start_date is a date in the past or today
- the end_date is a date in the future or today OR the number of
  participations (DealsParticipation model) is lower than the maximum
  number of participants of the deal (field nb_participants).

My model:

```
class Deals(models.Model):
    u"""List of deals available to the participant 
    """

    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand_Advertiser, blank=False, null=False, related_name='brands_of_deal')
    start_date = models.DateField(_("Date de debut"), blank=False, null=False, default=datetime.date.today)
    end_date = models.DateField(_("Date de fin"), blank=True, null=True)
    nb_participants=models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Nombre de participants maximum"), default=100, blank=True, null=True)


class DealsParticipation(TimeStampedModel):

    u"""Participation to deals by participants
    """

    deal = models.ForeignKey('Deals', blank=False, null=False, related_name='deal_participation')
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant, blank=False, null=False)
```

What I have tried:

```
class CurrentDealsView(ListView):
    model = models.Deals

    def get_queryset(self):
        #get all the deals having started in the past or today and closing in the future or today
        now = datetime.now()
        start_date_condition=Q(start_date__lte=now)
        end_date_condition = Q(end_date__gte=now) | Q(end_date__isnull=True)
        #get all the deals with a number of participations lower than the maximal number of participants
        nb_participants_condition=Q(nb_participants__gt=Count('deal_participation'))
        return models.Deals.objects.filter(start_date_condition & (end_date_condition | nb_participants_condition))
```

### **Solved!**

As explained by emulbreh, I had to use the count inside annotate:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    #get all the deals having started in the past or today and closing in the future or today
    now = datetime.now()
    start_date_condition=Q(start_date__lte=now)
    end_date_condition = Q(end_date__gte=now) | Q(end_date__isnull=True)
    date_conditions=models.Deals.objects.filter(start_date_condition & end_date_condition)

    #get all the deals with a number of participations lower than the maximal number of participants
    return date_conditions.annotate(participation_count=Count('deal_participation')).filter(nb_participants__gt=F('participation_count'))
```

Comment: There is no aggregate and no annotate in my code, so there is no aggregation, right? Do you want me to post the sql query that I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation functions (like `Count`) need to be used with `annotate()` or `aggregate()`. You can reference annotated fields from `filter()` or  `Q()`:

```
Deals.objects.annotate(
    participation_count=Count('deal_participation')
).filter(
    nb_participants__gt=F('participation_count')
)
```

There's an [example in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)